# Quando validar campos de um formulário em swing?

Tags: java, swing, validação

Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar sobre validação de campos de formulários em java desktop. Quando devo realizar as validações, na saída(focusLost) do campo ou no Pressionamento de teclas(keyPressed), ou outra forma mais adequada.

Por Exemplo:

Tenho um campo do tipo `JFormatTextField` com a mascara de ##/##/#### (data), estando meste campo que é obrigatório, quero sair da janela, então clico no botão sair, ele valida o campo mesmo assim, porque a validação está no focus, outra questão e esta validação estando no keyPress, caso eu não pressione enter e saia do campo ele não validará, qual a logica correta para este tipo de validação

```
private void txtDataCotFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                     
        if (txtDataCot.getText().equals("  /  /    ")) {
            //Limpa o lixo no campo
            txtDataCot.setValue(null);
            //Mensagem de validação
            MensagemPersJOptionPane.msgAttention(rootPane, "<html>Conflitos encontrados, Verifique:<br><br>&#8227; Informe a data do orçamento!</html>", MensagemPersJOptionPane.getMsgTitleValidacao());
            txtDataCot.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

**InputVerifiers:**

```
InputVerifier verifierQuant = new InputVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            final JTextComponent source = (JTextComponent) input;
            String text = source.getText();
            double number = Double.parseDouble(text.replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));
            if (number == 0 && !sair.equals("Sair")) {
                MensagemPersJOptionPane.msgAttention(rootPane, "<html>Conflito(s) encontrado(s), verifique! <br><br>&#8227; Não foi informada uma quantidade </html>",
                        MensagemPersJOptionPane.getMsgTitleValidacao());
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    };

    InputVerifier verifierProduct = new InputVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            final JTextComponent source = (JTextComponent) input;
            String text = source.getText();
            if (text.length() == 0 && !sair.equals("Sair")) {
                MensagemPersJOptionPane.msgAttention(rootPane, "<html>Conflito(s) encontrado(s), verifique! <br><br> &#8227; O produto não foi informado</html>",
                        MensagemPersJOptionPane.getMsgTitleValidacao());
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    };

InputVerifier verifier = new InputVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            final JTextComponent source = (JTextComponent) input;
            String text = source.getText();
            if ((text.equals("  /  /    "))) {
                MensagemPersJOptionPane.msgAttention(rootPane,
                        "<html>Conflitos encontrados, Verifique:<br><br>&#8227; Informe a data do orçamento!</html>",
                        MensagemPersJOptionPane.getMsgTitleValidacao());
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
```

**Estanciados no construtor**

```
txtQuant.setInputVerifier(verifierQuant);
txtProduto.setInputVerifier(verifierProduct);
txtDataCot.setInputVerifier(verifier);
```

**Ação para o botão sair**

```
private void ActionSair() {
        this.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Depende da sua aplicação, mas eu não usaria a perda de foco pra validar um campo, e sim, alertar ao usuário quanto ao preenchimento deste.

Comment: Ulisses, ao inves de postar a solução na resposta, você pode responder sua propria pergunta com ela. Pra ficar de acordo com o site, talvez seja melhor fazer isso. Você também pode marcar sua solução como a correta.

Comment: Ok, Eu ia fazer isso, mas apareceu uma pergunta se eu queria realmente fazer isso, fiquei na dúvida, desculpe. Ainda estou acostumando com o site.

Comment: O que são esses códigos adicionados? Se forem respostas, como já te falei, você deve editar sua resposta abaixo e adicionar nela.

Comment: diegofm da uma olhada nos comentarios da minha resposta que você vai entender o que esta acontecendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como é um formulário, você deve ter um Button para salvar ou prosseguir, dependendo do seu formulário.
Quando preciso montar formulários desse modo, sempre coloco um método pra verificar se existe algum campo vazio, ao pressionar o Button SALVAR, caso exista, eu abro uma janela de alerta pro usuário, para que ele possa preencher o campo antes de prosseguir.

Espero ter te dado uma ideia de como prosseguir.

Comment: É possivel usar também o `InputVerifier`, que fará as validações em tempo de execução, sem precisar esperar o submit para validar. É mais complicado, mas economiza algumas linhas de código com inúmeros listeners.

Comment: Não conhecia o InputVerifier , Mas obrigado pela dica, vou pesquisar sobre o assunto.

Comment: Eu fazia da forma como o Edumachdo tinha dito, eu acho até melhor, mas o patrão enjoado e cheio de frescura, gosta de validação no campo, fica copiando ideia de um outro sistema utilizado aqui. Utilizei o inputVerifier e deu certo.

Comment: Encontrei apenas um problema no inputverifier, ele fez o que eu queria, mas quando clico no botão cancelar(que é um dispose) para sair da janela, ele não permite porque o campo não está preenchido.

Comment: Tem como postar o seu código completo??
pelo menos os Buttons e o inputVerifier.
Para que possamos analisar melhor o problema.

Comment: Verifica se ajuda. coloquei o código do inputverifier e do botao

Answer (score 1):

**Com as respostas que recebi e com ajuda do pessoal, resolvi desta forma:**

```
InputVerifier verifier = new InputVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            final JTextComponent source = (JTextComponent) input;
            String text = source.getText();
            if ((text.equals("  /  /    "))) {
                MensagemPersJOptionPane.msgAttention(rootPane,
                        "<html>Conflitos encontrados, Verifique:<br><br>&#8227; Informe a data do orçamento!</html>",
                        MensagemPersJOptionPane.getMsgTitleValidacao());
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    };

txtDataCot.setInputVerifier(verifier);
```