# obrigar usuário a preencher os edittext

Tags: android, actionbar

Eu tenho alguns EditText e preciso que todos sejam preenchidos, caso o usuário não preencha e tente apertar o botão para continuar as caixas de texto devem mostrar um erro. porem esse botão esta na action bar e não sei onde devo aplicar a verificação

Comment: é um image button

Answer (score 1):

Fala Carlos,

Você está inflando um xml com os items da sua actionBar, correto?

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
   inflater.inflate(com.sample.R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}
```

Então, você tem que ter um método que controla os clicks, exemplo:

```
public boolean OnOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
      case R.id.enviarForm:
          //verifica se o campo de texto está nulo
          return true;  
      default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }   
}
```

Abraços.

Comment: olá cheguei agora em casa, vou testar isso, Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: eu não entendi o que seria R.id.enviarForm:

Comment: É o id do botão (item) que tem lá no seu menu, que você inflou, posta o XML do seu menu pra gente ver.

Answer (score 0):

Mas eu colocaria um método, que verifica se o campo é null ou não, para ser ativado quando o usuário clica no Button.

De uma olhada nesse link.
Espero que ajude.
[Quando validar campos de um formulário em swing?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142408/quando-validar-campos-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio-em-swing/142411#142411)