# Prevenir inserção no banco com String " " (com espaço no nome)

Tags: java, exceção

Meu problema consiste no seguinte:

Tenho um JTextField que vai receber o nome da minha entidade, vai passar pro controller, a qual vai criar o bean e por fim, chamar o DAO para inserir no banco. Coisa simples um CRUD básico.

O campo da tabela no banco está `NOT NULL`, pois não faria sentido estiver em branco.

Pensando em: **Make It Simple!** fiz o seguinte no método que será responsável pelos eventos na JDialog, teriro os espaços vazio do inicio do nome e uso um JOptionPane caso o JTextField esteja vazio.

Entretanto seremos avaliados também pela elegância do código, melhores formas de resolver os problema, por exemplo utilização de Pattern.
Seguindo essa lógica no método, do controller, responsável por instanciar o DAO e inserir no banco um retorno booleano apenas, para avisar ao método que chamou se foi sucedido ou não a inserção. Neste caso, o método vai verificar se o nome da entidade está null, e se existe um nome igual já cadastrado no banco, instanciando uma ArrayList com todos os nomes cadastrado e utilizando de um ForEach para verificação, caso já existe o nome retorna false.

Mas, como disse seremos avaliado pela elegância do código, então imagine fazer um exceção e tratar isso retornando caso o método retorne falso. buscando mais informações eu li:

[Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21933/como-melhor-tratar-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-java/21939#21939)
[É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15261/%C3%89-uma-boa-pr%C3%A1tica-lan%C3%A7ar-exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o-nesses-casos/15263#15263)
[Exception vs RuntimeException, quando utilizar um ou outro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55624/exception-vs-runtimeexception-quando-utilizar-um-ou-outro)

E algumas outras coisas a mais para melhor meu entendimento que clareou um pouco, mas, ainda estou com a duvida: Desta maneira está correto ou seria mais, digamos "elegante", tratar como uma exceção?

Códigos:

Método do botão salvar:

```
public void setupEvents() {
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tfNameNewDiscipline.getText().trim();
            ControllerDiscipline controller;

            if(tfNameNewDiscipline.getText().isEmpty())
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite um nome para a Disciplina", "Erro no cadastro da Disciplina", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            else  {
                controller = new ControllerDiscipline();
                if(controller.addDiscipline(tfNameNewDiscipline.getText()) == false)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Disciplina já existe", "Erro no cadastro da Disciplina", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Método da classe controller que adiciona ao banco:

```
public boolean addDiscipline(String name) {

    DisciplineDAO dao = new DisciplineDAO();
    Discipline entity = new Discipline();

    entity.setName(name);

    if (entity.getName().isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    ArrayList<Discipline> disciplines = new ArrayList<>();
    disciplines.addAll(dao.searchData());

    for(Discipline discipline : disciplines) {
        if(entity.getName().equals(discipline.getName()))
            return false;
    }

    dao.insert(entity);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Já pesquisou por `InputVerifier`? Ele insere uma limitação em runtime no campo, que caso esteja vazio, nem deixa o actionperformed ser executado. Dá uma olhada [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142607/28595), tem um exemplo lá.

Comment: assim logo após fazer a pergunta, achei, entretanto ela vai me ajudar com o JtextField mas, para validar a inserção não... mas, acho que vou usá-lo, pois acredito que ficou melhor a implementação do exemplo que você citou.

Comment: O objetivo é evitar que campos vazios fossem inseridos no banco, disparando exceções pela restrição do campo? Filtrando logo antes do usuário fazer o save, você já está evitando ter que se preocupar esse tipo de exceções, tendo que encher seu códigos de try/catchs. :)

Comment: Desta maneira então você acha que já é mais que o suficiente... não existe a necessidade de criar uma exceção para este caso?

Comment: Sim, o inputverifier não vai deixar o formulario ser submetido até que o campo seja maior que zero, isso, claro, supondo que você aplique esta condição no `verify`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fala amigo!

**Sobre as exceções**: não encontrei em nenhum lugar o lançamento ou captura de Exceptions.. Tá implementado mesmo?
Mesmo vocês sendo avaliados pela elegância do código, eu **acho** exagero tratar validações de `view` com Exceptions.. Acho bem mais válido tratar suas validações de regra de negócio (camada Business ou Controller: depende de como você está implementando né hehe) com Exceptions do que a View.

**Sobre a validação de " "**: Eu costumo usar a classe `StringUtils` do pacote `org.apache.commons.lang3` para fazer esse tipo de validação.
Ela tem (se não me engano), um método chamado `isNotNullOrEmpty()` que funciona que é uma beleza! :)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Não eu não implementei apenas estava pensando em fazer isso, mas, estava na duvida se é exagero ou não.